# iOS6 failed to check string contains only alpha-numeric chars

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, unicode

I am using this code to check if a user input string contains only alpha-numeric chars in iOS6:

```
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmedString = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet];
BOOL valid = [trimmedString isEqualToString:@""];
```

but here's the result of running this piece of code:

[image]

Note that the `text` (string to be checked) contains only Chinese chars, but after trim by `alphaSet` it becomes an empty string and passed the verification.

I also tried this code and it is also not working:

```
- (BOOL) isAlphaNumeric: (NSString *) text
{
    NSCharacterSet *unwantedCharacters =
    [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    return ([text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:unwantedCharacters].location == NSNotFound) ? YES : NO;
}
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Do I need to encode the input text somehow before I do the check?

Currently I get the string directly from iOS6's `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`'s last `replacementText` parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `alphanumericCharacterSet` also seems to contain the chinese letters, so the result is "correct". Apple doesn't document it this way but I've seen a few postings (e.g. from GNUStep) that seem to indicate it. (Also note that Apple *does* document that this set contains characters that you might not want: *Informally, this set is the set of all characters used as basic units of alphabets, syllabaries, ideographs, and digits.*).

A simple yet inelegant workaround is to define the character set yourself, if all you want is the english alphabet without any foreign letters like `Ü` or `ß`:

```
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890"];
```

When you're targeting iOS >= 7, one of the `URL*AllowedCharacterSet` might be of interest. See the [NSCharacterSet documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.